# limit concurrent user logins in Plone/Zope

Tags: limit, plone, zope

I want to limit the number of active sessions a user can have in Plone/Zope. We are selling access to digital content and ideally want to limit how many concurrent logins can use one set of credentials.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 3):

You can try the NoDuplicateLogin PAS plugin.  http://plone.org/products/noduplicatelogin

Comment: Thanks this seems to do exactly what I want!

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore; try https://pypi.org/project/Products.NoDuplicateLogin/ instead.